# TCL wait time in countdown

Tags: tcl, eggdrop

```
if {[info exists queue($variable)} {
    if {[expr [unixtime] - $queue($variable)]<86400} {
        set calctime [expr [unixtime] - queue($variable)]
        putquick "PRIVMSG $channel :you cant because you need to wait $calctime"
    }
}
set queue($variable) [unixtime]
```

I have got this code in my Tcl script, so each user will need to wait 24 hours before can do the command again. 
I would to put a countdown showing how much time (hours,minutes,seconds) they need to wait before can do it again. But at the moment the only thing I can do is put the seconds counting with the `$calctime`

Any idea how I can do it? Definitly my try of `$calctime` is a failure :P

Comment: Note the if condition is already processed by expr, so `if {([unixtime] - $queue($variable))<86400} {...`

Comment: `putquick` is for stuff that are probably more urgent than sending your message, like kicks and bans. Use `puthelp` instead, or your channel could for example be flooded by someone while the eggdrop is busy with channel message(s). http://eggwiki.org/Queues#General_principle

Answer (score 1):

Treat the seconds as relative to the epoch with [clock format](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/clock.htm#M7). Don't leave out `-gmt 1`, or you'll get a number of hours wrong. How many depends on what timezone you're in.

```
putquick "PRIVMSG $channel :you cant because you need to wait \
  [clock format $calctime -format "%T" -gmt 1]"
```

Or calculate it yourself:

```
set seconds [expr {$calctime % 60}]
set calctime [expr {$calctime / 60}]
set minutes [expr {$calctime % 60}]
set hours [expr {$calctime / 60}]
putquick "PRIVMSG $channel :you cant because you need to wait \
  $hours hours, $minutes minutes and $seconds seconds"
```

Comment: Actually, the first method assumes that the epoch is at midnight (any-date-here 00:00:00), and I don't think Tcl 8.4 guarantees that. Tcl 8.5 does.

Comment: ptrzebie, can you help me there? I tried what you said, and the result was: you cant because you need to wait 0 hours, 3 minutes and 8 seconds . but What I need is a countdown from 24hours to 0, not from 0 to 24 :x

Comment: @user676032 Since you're not interested in when the user last used the command, but rather when he/she can use it again, save **that** in your array elements instead, i.e. add `24 * 60 * 60` when you save the time. Then use `$queue($variable) - [unixtime]` instead of `[unixtime] - $queue($variable)`. And for god's sake, change the variable name `queue` to e.g. `last_used` and `variable` to e.g. `nick`.

Answer (score 0):

To display the time that the user have to wait you can use the eggdrop specific command `duration`.

```
if {[info exists queue($variable)} {
    if {[clock seconds] - $queue($variable) < 60*60*24 } {
        set calctime [duration [expr {[clock seconds] - queue($variable)}]]
        putmsg $channel "you cant because you need to wait $calctime"
        return
    }
}
set queue($variable) [clock seconds]
# Do the command stuff
```